# Deal with edits that merely change indenting convention in code samples

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, code-formatting, etiquette

There are so many coding conventions out there, in particular with regard to how much indenting to use. I don't think it makes any sense to discuss which one is easier to read in the same way as it makes sense to discuss whether blue is a nice color.

Recently I get the indent "fixed" in code samples. This is annoying.

Is there any better way to deal with the annoyance than just going away and ignoring it?

Comment: Where do you want to deal with these edits? In the review queues? Edits to your own posts? In posts you see around while browsing the site?

Comment: @yivi Edits in my own posts.

Comment: With any edits to your posts, you have the last word about accepting or rejecting third party edits. Be reasonable while excercising this right, though.

Comment: The edit you are talking about was in a question, the editor should not have done that at all. Code in questions should remain untouched (except for adding code formatting with 4 spaces). Upon reviewing some edits by that user, there's actually a pattern here. Perhaps a moderator should reach out to them?

Answer (score 5):

If the edits were made to your own posts, you can always roll them back, or even reject them if you happen to be online when the edit is made.

Do this if:

- You believe the edit made the post worse than it was originally
- The edit changed your post into something you disagree with
- You believe the edit is absolutely irrelevant

Be careful with the last one, though. If you consider the edit superficial but not harmful, and the edit was made by other user with full edit privileges, you do not want to get into an edit war for something you yourself consider irrelevant.

If you really feel better rolling it back, do so. But if the other user rolls back **your** edit or edits back the changes, just flag the post for moderator attention and explain the situation. But make sure that the edit wasn't really doing something good for your post in the first place.

If your post was originally a question, as Stijn mentioned in a comment to your question, other users should be even more careful of suggesting edits to code; so feel even more free about rolling these edits back. But again, try to use anything the editors suggested, as more often than not editors are trying to help making your post better in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Reject them in the review queue, and rollback if they get through. If you pay attention to your inbox, it's not too hard.

Comment: Do note that in the review queue, you should be aware of whitespace-sensitive languages. A _fixed indent_ edit that just edits a couple of spaces in Python can certainly be a good edit

Comment: Not an indent aware language.